Why don't decimal-floating-point numbers have CPU level support like float point numbers in personal computers?
In languages ​​where Decimal exists (C#, Python), it is slower than float/double because it is not supported at the hardware level. So why don't decimal-floating-point, have hardware implementation for execution speed like FPU for float point numbers, if even decimal-floating-point are in IEEE 754-2008 standard?
The similar question was asked 15 years ago, but still in usual CPU we don't have decimal-floating-point support: Why aren't Floating-Point Decimal numbers hardware accelerated like Floating-Point Binary numbers?. The question that was asked 15 years ago, and then the answer was something like this: binary appeared earlier, now the decimal format has been added to the standard, and most likely, its hardware implementation will appear in the near future in PCs, but after 15 years we do not have this module in PCs, why? This is what I’m asking.
What I've changed in question: I have changed BID, DPD to decimal-floating-point and link to make my question more understandable

Few applications need it and it costs silicon real estate to implement: cost increase for HW vendors that cannot be recouped by additional HW sales. To my knowledge, IBM mainframe (z-Series, latest model z15) is the only platform that provides DPF accelerators, because there is a lot of non-{technical | scientific} high performance computing taking place on those machines.

BCD packed decimal support for signed 18 digits is still present in the on chip legacy x87 silicon of Intel & AMD CPUs although with an awkward 10byte structure length and comparatively slow implementation it was never much used.

@MartinBrown: Yes, fbld and fbstp (load/store with conversion between BCD integer and x87 80-bit float) still exist as part of the ISA, but they're microcoded as a huge number of uops so it's not real hardware support.  (Like 274 to 288 uops for fbstp on Zen 1 through 4, up from as low as 210 on K10.  And on Intel, PPro microcoded it as 165 uops, with later uarches using more, like 260 on Skylake, but then down to 226 on Ice Lake.)  fbld is fewer, eg 9 uops so I guess it's not just naive 1 digit at a time total = total*10 + digit, maybe SIMD

I got those uop counts from https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf .  Another good source is https://uops.info/table.html

Related: Why do computers use binary numbers in IEEE754 fraction instead of BCD or DPD? - comments discuss some of the downsides.  But partly it's a chicken/egg problem.  Lack of language support gives low motivation for CPU architects to provide HW support, which in turn makes decimal FP types a niche language feature that many omit.

I think one example of true hardware support in a popular CPU family (at least by volume) is Cordic accelerator on the STM ARM cortex coprocessor as described here (1 extra bit precision per machine cycle). Trouble is that modern CPUs with SIMD parallel algorithms have become so good now that for most cases library functions are already fast enough.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/169452/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/78895305/781723.  Once again, please do not post the same question on multiple sites.  (See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/169419/why-do-computers-use-binary-numbers-in-ieee754-fraction-instead-of-bcd-or-dpd#comment350086_169419.)

How does this question differ from the one it references? The question seems to be the same and several answers haven’t aged. Note that if you are just looking for up to date answers, a bounty on the old question is more appropriate.

@MisterMiyagi This question is very close to the previous, but get 75 reputation on SO today is a very difficult task, on SO on Russian, get more than 75 rep. ia much easier, so there I just will just add a bounty. And the last reference is trying to get an answer for a very different question from these

This question is similar to: Why aren't Floating-Point Decimal numbers hardware accelerated like Floating-Point Binary numbers?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MisterMiyagi I have already found this question before and even write about it in the description, this is not the same, and why I have already written in question

@NikolaiVorobiev "this is not the same, and why I have already written in question" I’m not sure where I’m the question you intended to have done so. The only part that seems to address differences is "What I've changed in question …" but that does not match the content of either question. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I repeat the question that was asked 15 years ago, and then the answer was something like this: binary appeared earlier, now the decimal format has been added to the standard, and most likely, its hardware implementation will appear in the near future in PCs, but after 15 years we do not have this module in PCs, why? This is my question

@NikolaiVorobiev The way I think of it is: There are two applications that seem to need decimal arithmetic: (1) financial calculations and (2) beginning programmers who expect their computer programs to give the same answers as their calculators.  For (1), fixed point is a recommended and practical alternative, or as mentioned, IBM still sells decimal-based hardware for heavy financial number-crunching. For (2) — which gets asked about on SO almost every day — we have Is floating-point math broken?

Don't get me wrong — I would love to see more widespread support for decimal floating point.  But my wish for it is more for fun and for intellectual curiosity, not out of any commercially-compelling mandate that might compel CPU manufacturers to devote silicon and design time to.

So: why do you think we need decimal floating-point support?  Don't say "because it's more accurate", because it's not.  For the values it can't represent, it rounds differently, but for most applications (except for financial ones), it's pretty arbitrary which way you round.

Because there isn't sufficient demand to make it worthwhile for chip manufacturers to include hardware support for decimal arithmetic.  This is fundamentally a economic / business decision.  As real-world programmers, we just have to use the hardware that is available.  So this is not a programming question.

The IBM z-series processors do have hardware support for decimal floating point.  These are very high-end "spare no expense" machines, so it is not too suprising to see it there.
As to why more commodity processors do not, it is mostly a matter of cost and demand.  Demand is low, as decimal floating point still has rounding issues (they just crop up with different values than binary floating point).

Yes, but DPD and double store the same amount of dec digits(15-16), so if you will use first, your calculations will be more correct, won’t they?

@NikolaiVorobiev:  They'll be rounded to the nearest decimal digit, rather than to the nearest bit, which arguably makes them less accurate.  But the key is they'll be different, and if you are expecting decimal rounding, you may be surprised by binary rounding.

@NikolaiVorobiev Decimal math isn’t any more generally correct than binary math. Many, many, many numerical tasks are not biased towards decimal.

There are some (e.g., finance related) problems, where decimal rounding is required (which however mostly need fixed precision). Unless that is the case, or for some reason, you need to convert lots of decimal input/output, there is no benefit in using decimal over binary.

And what about personal computers?

@NikolaiVorobiev Double precision reals can represent the global GDP in $ and still have one decimal place to spare (which for a number that is optimistically +/- 1% seems overkill to me). 15 good decimal digits is more than enough for just about any financial calculation if programmers know what they are doing (far too many don't).

Having fixed point hardware support instead of only the floating point support, would indeed be great.
The current feasible solution is to use (intnum, scale) with the meant value intnum * 10-scale.
That floating point has so much support is due to many geometrical functions like sin, cos, ln, e etcera which are optimizable, i.e. in hardware.
It is more a shame that fixed point did not get much language support, besides in COBOL and SQL.
Hardware support of a new generation would be nice and there also already exists a better floating point standard. However reality does not favour ideal and elegant architectures.

Feedback (why I mention fixed point w.r.t. DPD and such)
Floating point is an approximation with (negative) powers of 2 in the standard. Fixed point has to (implicitly) use powers of 10. Hence BCD, Densely Packed Decimals or indeed an int64 large integer come to play. My assumption was that such formats are near the human representation of digits in a decimal number, and primarily useful for fixed point.

Fixed point is still used in some price/power sensitive DSP applications. Analogue Devices discuss the trade offs between these hardware choices in this short review. int64 isn't a bad proxy for doing fixed point arithmetic if you are careful.

Thank you for your answer! Can you just explain how fixed point connected with DPD and Decimal64?

And what a type of Rust, C#, Python decimal(BID, DPD and so on)?

For C++ you can easily find (or self implement) fixed-point libraries. There is probably just to much variety to have one standard solution which fits all purposes.

geometrical functions like sin, cos, ln, e etcera which are optimizable, i.e. in hardware. - Do you have any examples of hardware support for sin or cos in popular CPUs?  If you were thinking of x86 fsin and fcos, those are actually slow microcode not really specialized hardware.

Software implementations of sincos using only basic operations (+ - * / and sqrt) can run at about the same speed as the CPU instructions (or using SIMD for parallel results) with similar precision.  (e.g. not using extended-precision range-reduction; https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/ / Accuracy of FSIN and other x87 trigonometric instructions on AMD processors)

So there isn't special hardware that x86 fsin uses to run faster than we can do with basic software, and there's no SSE/AVX version of those instructions.  log / exp are different, especially for base 2 logs for binary floating point, because separating the exponent and mantissa allows a polynomial approximation over a very small range.  Xeon Phi had vexp2ps (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vexp2ps) for a fast approximation of 2^x (as part of AVX-512ER which only Xeon Phi had, not mainstream CPUs), but software can do well too, esp. with vgetmantps to save on FP bithacks.

Ok, how DPD connected with fixed point?

@NikolaiVorobiev indeed it was an assumption on my side; added some feedback to my answer. Many comments worthwhile reading. I was not aware that efficient languages like Rust and C# had good library support - my daily bread lies with java.

Fixed point has to (implicitly) use powers of 10. - binary fixed-point is commonly used.  e.g. the actual value represented is integer / 256 if you're using the low 8 bits as fraction bits, the rest as integer.  Since fixup after multiplying is a division by the scale factor, for binary fixed point it's just a right shift.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic#Choice_of_scaling_factors mentions that often the scale factor is "a power of the base used to represent the integers internally", which for binary computers is 2.  Powers of 10 are worth it for some uses, of course.

Fixed point can use binary or decimal (or any other) base.  Indeed, implementing binary fixed point with integers and shifts is trivial (and common in many domains).  Decimal fixed point is only a little bit more expensive as you need mul/div/mod by a power of 10 rather than just a power of 2 (what the shift gives you), and only when implementing a mul/div.  Most hardware also has "widening" mul/div (mul result 2x as many bits as the two sources) which is particularly convenient for binary fixed point, and less so for decimal.

@ChrisDodd and others: I am aware of fixed point binary but that will give a human decimal representation that is an approximation too. I (erroneously) assumed that fixed point has its primary use for money and such and would be base 10 to avoid approximations. I staand corrected, probably in embedded software,a bit more complex then thermometers and such. I leave my answer for the interesting comments.
